# Extract Names from Field (Regex)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract First and Last name from a string that looks like this:

```
CN=First\, Last,OU=Standard users,OU=Users,OU=Place,OU=DOMAIN,DC=dfe,DC=stuff,DC=asdf

([^CN=,\\])([a-zA-Z]*)?(?!OU)
```

My attempt is above, but it obviously doesn't work.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Thanks

Comment: Is the `CN` field guaranteed to always be the first one?

Comment: Yes, it's always going to be the first ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
^CN=(.*?)\\, (.*?),
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/kW6bJ7/1).  It uses two capturing groups for first and last names with the other static text around them.

Answer (score 0):

```
CN=(.*)\\, ([^,]*),
```

This should get your First until the \, and last until the next comma.

Answer (score 0):

You could come up with:

CN=(?P[^,]+),\s*
(?P[^,]+)

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wA9uM2/1).

Answer (score 0):

In the regex you have tried, the `[^CN=,\\]` this part will do exactly the reverse of what you need, like will match the characters except `CN=,\\` these. 
You can use:

```
^CN=[^,]+,\s+[^,]+
```

Answer (score 0):

`^CN=(.+)\\, (.+?),`

This will get you `First` in the first capture group and `Last` in the second capture group, assuming everything matches the pattern of line starting with `CN=`, then first name, then `\,`, then last name, followed by `,`. First and last are will not be limited to only letters though.

When you put the `^` inside of brackets like you attempted, `[^CN=,\\]`, then you are telling Regex to look for any characters except `C`, `N`, `=`, `,`, and `\`.